# How many different combinations can make up $\$59.30$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations, combinations

How many different combinations can make up $\$59.30$?   Anything from $59.29 + 0.01$ to $0.01$ added together $5930$ times.

My dad is looking to see in our financial logs where a discrepancy lies of $\$59.30$. I have done some university calc, and wanted to be able to help him. Even if the solutions are a huge number, maybe that huge number would show him that taking up this much time on this is illogical. Would this be something to do with factorials, combinatorials, summation or p&c?? Better yet, is there a program that could be written that can automate all of these options so that I could help him to actually find his solution, or is the number nearly infinite?

Comment: to be clear, that means that the NUMBER of objects being added together can be anything from 2 to 5930

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It seems that you are asking about the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $5930$.  According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=partitions+of+5930+), the partition function of $5930$ is $1478155093890337380326071288416171674201978869874500511310910604860140292514769264$

Comment: Does the order matter? if yes, good luck, you can only compute it with a computer

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace:  If the order matters it is easy:  $2^{5929}$.  Imagine a row of $5930$ pennies and you get to choose where to draw a dividing line between the pieces.

Comment: I don't think the number of combinations is useful.  It will be enormous.  What matters is whether you can check at arbitrary points whether things are in balance.   If so, you can do a binary search to find the date of the first discrepancy, fix that, and go on.

Comment: @RossMillikan If I'm not mistaken this is the number of partitions, if you know how to compute this, call the committee for the fields medal (the number of summands is not fixed) Or is it when the order does not matter?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace:  no, it is the number of compositions, where $100+5830$ is different from $5830+100$.  That makes it much easier.  Those two are equivalent as partitions, which is what makes counting partitions hard.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes thanks for the precision, I have mistaken both, I knew one was feasible and the other not :)

Comment: If $59.30$ came from summing $n$ entries, then question is how many ways to partition 5930 into upto $n$ groups; one for each entry. Since entries are distinct, order would matter. This can be solved as placing $n-1$ dividers among 5930 objects in a row, inclusive of the ends (since some entries could have 0 contribution). So choosing $n-1$ locations among the 5931 possible, allowing for different dividers to have the same location, but not counting permutations of dividers as separate combinations. This feels like $\frac{{5931}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ to me, but clearly this is not always an integer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are asking for is the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) of $5930$,

the number of distinct ways of representing $5930$ as a sum of positive integers.

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=partitions+of+5930+), the partition function of $5930$ is

$1478155093890337380326071288416171674201978869874500511310910604860140292514769264$

, which is a huge number indeed.